# Update Mysql Json Column

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Example the `data` column has

> {"default_account":188,"default_bu-207":948}

```
update user_preference 
    set data = JSON_REMOVE(data,'$.default_bu-207')
where JSON_EXTRACT(data,'$.default_bu-207') = 948
```

for this query i am getting error

> Invalid JSON path expression.

The error is around character position 16.*

tried escaping `-` but it is throwing same error

Comment: Well to help we would have to know what the JSON Document looked like in the `data` column

Comment: @RiggsFolly example added in the question

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html says:

> ### JSON Path Syntax
>
> ...
>
> Names of keys must be double-quoted strings or valid ECMAScript identifiers (see Identifier Names and Identifiers, in the ECMAScript Language Specification).

Since your key name contains a punctuation character, you must use double quotes:

```
... JSON_REMOVE(data,'$."default_bu-207"') ...
```